# Why are multiple Browser instances opening when I am trying to run a single Test Case script in this case?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pom.xml

I was trying to automate a few sample Test Scenarios using Page Factory Model and Cucumber but don't seem to understand why multiple driver instances when I try to run a single test case.

When I am trying to run only Test Case 1 through Runner.java file

```
package execution;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "D:\\Eclipse Wokspace\\EcommerceProject\\Features\\Test1.feature", 
                 glue = { "stepDefinition" }, 
                 plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt", "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
        "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml","com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html" }, 
                 dryRun = false, 
                 monochrome = true, 
                 strict = true)
public class Runner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(
                new File("D:\\Eclipse Wokspace\\EcommerceProject\\src\\test\\resources\\extent-config.xml"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", "Windows 10 " + "64 Bit");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Selenium", "3.7.0");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Maven", "3.5.2");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Java Version", "1.8.0_151");
    }
}
```

@Before and @After of other two Step Definition classes also seem to be invoked as visible from the logs below

```
2018-08-05 14:16:16,358  INFO [main] SameCostSteps:25 - ************* Test Case 2 Begin ***************
2018-08-05 14:16:31,264  INFO [main] HomePage:17 - PageFactory setup of HomePage
2018-08-05 14:16:31,321 DEBUG [main] HomePage:22 - Click on Mobile Link
2018-08-05 14:16:33,077  INFO [main] HomePage:24 - Navigating to Mobile Page
2018-08-05 14:16:33,083  INFO [main] MobilePage:35 - PageFactory setup of MobilePage
2018-08-05 14:16:33,123  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:26 - ***************************************************************
2018-08-05 14:16:33,126  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:27 - ******************** Test Case 3 Begin ************************
2018-08-05 14:16:33,127  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:28 - ***************************************************************
2018-08-05 14:16:47,370  INFO [main] HomePage:17 - PageFactory setup of HomePage
2018-08-05 14:16:47,371 DEBUG [main] HomePage:22 - Click on Mobile Link
2018-08-05 14:16:48,771  INFO [main] HomePage:24 - Navigating to Mobile Page
2018-08-05 14:16:48,773  INFO [main] MobilePage:35 - PageFactory setup of MobilePage
2018-08-05 14:16:48,777  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:24 - ************* Test Case 1 Begin ***************
2018-08-05 14:17:01,832  INFO [main] HomePage:17 - PageFactory setup of HomePage
2018-08-05 14:17:01,833 DEBUG [main] HomePage:22 - Click on Mobile Link
2018-08-05 14:17:03,563  INFO [main] HomePage:24 - Navigating to Mobile Page
2018-08-05 14:17:03,567  INFO [main] MobilePage:35 - PageFactory setup of MobilePage
2018-08-05 14:17:04,411  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:40 - Retrieving initial unsorted product list
2018-08-05 14:17:04,411  INFO [main] MobilePage:47 - Collecting a list of Products
2018-08-05 14:17:04,872  INFO [main] MobilePage:41 - Selecting value from the dropdown list
2018-08-05 14:17:06,332  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:48 - Retrieving final sorted list
2018-08-05 14:17:06,333  INFO [main] MobilePage:47 - Collecting a list of Products
2018-08-05 14:17:06,453  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:51 - Sorting the unsorted array string by Name
2018-08-05 14:17:06,454  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:53 - Verifying that the products have been sorted by Name
2018-08-05 14:17:06,454  INFO [main] MobilePage:58 - Verifying that the products have been sorted by Name
2018-08-05 14:17:06,459  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:57 - ############# Test Case 1 Passed ###########
2018-08-05 14:17:06,463  INFO [main] SameCostSteps:33 - ************* Test Case 2 End ******************
2018-08-05 14:17:09,747  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:37 - ***************************************************************
2018-08-05 14:17:09,749  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:38 - ******************** Test Case 3 End   ************************
2018-08-05 14:17:09,750  INFO [main] CartLimitSteps:39 - ***************************************************************
2018-08-05 14:17:09,770  INFO [main] SortByNameSteps:33 - ************* Test Case 1 End   ***************
```

As visible from the log above @Before and @After is being executed for all the Step Definition Classes even one I am running only Test1.feature file.

I don't seem to understand why this is happening as it is causing a lot of browser instances to open unnecessarily.

Code for other classes is as follows :

**Page Factory Classes:**

A) *HomePage.java*

```
package pageFactory;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Util.BasePage;

public class HomePage extends BasePage{
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class);

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"nav\"]/ol/li[1]/a")
    WebElement mobileLink;

    public HomePage() {
        log.info("PageFactory setup of HomePage");
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    public MobilePage clickMobile() {
        log.debug("Click on Mobile Link");
        mobileLink.click();
        log.info("Navigating to Mobile Page");
        return new MobilePage();
    }
}
```

B) *MobilePage.java*

```
package pageFactory;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.Assert;

import Util.BasePage;

public class MobilePage extends BasePage {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MobilePage.class);

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"top\"]/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select")
    WebElement SortBy;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
    List<WebElement> products;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"product-price-1\"]/span")
    WebElement xperiaPrice;

    @FindBy(id="product-collection-image-1")
    WebElement xperiaImg;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"top\"]/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/button")
    WebElement addToCartBtn;


    public MobilePage() {
        log.info("PageFactory setup of MobilePage");
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void sortByIndex(int val) {
        Select dlSort = new Select(SortBy);
        log.info("Selecting value from the dropdown list");
        dlSort.selectByIndex(val);

    }

    public String[] retrieveProductNames() {
        log.info("Collecting a list of Products");
        String[] productList = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        for (WebElement el : products) {
            productList[i] = el.getText();
            i++;
        }
        return productList;
    }

    public void verifySorting(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
        log.info("Verifying that the products have been sorted by Name");
        Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(array1, array2), "The products have not been sorted proerly");
    }

    public String getXperiaPrice() {
        return xperiaPrice.getText();
    }

    public XperiaPage clickOnXperia() {
        xperiaImg.click();
        return new XperiaPage();
    }

    public ShoppingCartPage addToCart() {
        addToCartBtn.click();
        return new ShoppingCartPage();
    }

}
```

C) XperiaPage.java

```
package pageFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Util.BasePage;

public class XperiaPage extends BasePage{
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"product-price-1\"]/span")
    WebElement xperiaPrice;

    public XperiaPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    public String getXperiaPrice() {
        return xperiaPrice.getText();
    }
}
```

**Step Definition Files**

A) *Test Case 1*

```
package stepDefinition;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import Util.BasePage;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import pageFactory.HomePage;
import pageFactory.MobilePage;

public class SortByNameSteps {
    public HomePage objHomePage;
    public MobilePage objMobilePage;
    public Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SortByNameSteps.class);
    public String[] unsorted;
    public String[] sorted;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        log.info("************* Test Case 1 Begin ***************");
        BasePage.initialization();
        objHomePage = new HomePage();
        objMobilePage = objHomePage.clickMobile();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        log.info("************* Test Case 1 End   ***************");
        BasePage.closeSession();
    }

    @When("^Select Name from the DropDownList$")
    public void select_Name_from_the_DropDownList() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Retrieving initial unsorted product list");
        unsorted = objMobilePage.retrieveProductNames();
        objMobilePage.sortByIndex(1);
    }

    @Then("^Verify that the Products have been sorted by Name$")
    public void verify_that_the_Products_have_been_sorted_by_Name() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Retrieving final sorted list");
        sorted = objMobilePage.retrieveProductNames();

        log.info("Sorting the unsorted array string by Name");
        Arrays.sort(unsorted);
        log.info("Verifying that the products have been sorted by Name");

        try {
            objMobilePage.verifySorting(unsorted, sorted);
            log.info("############# Test Case 1 Passed ###########");
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("############# Test Case 1 Failed  ###########");
        }

    }

}
```

B) *Test Case 2*

```
package stepDefinition;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.Assert;

import Util.BasePage;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import pageFactory.HomePage;
import pageFactory.MobilePage;
import pageFactory.XperiaPage;

public class SameCostSteps {
    public HomePage home;
    public MobilePage mobile;
    public XperiaPage xperia;
    public String detailCost;
    public String listCost;
    public Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SameCostSteps.class);

    @Before
    public void tearUp() {
        log.info("************* Test Case 2 Begin ***************");
        BasePage.initialization();
        home = new HomePage();
        mobile = home.clickMobile();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        log.info("************* Test Case 2 End ******************");
        BasePage.closeSession();
    }

    @When("^Read the cost of Sony Xperia$")
    public void read_the_cost_of_Sony_Xperia() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Fetching cost of product on List Page");
        listCost = mobile.getXperiaPrice();
    }

    @When("^Click on Sony Xperia Mobile$")
    public void click_on_Sony_Xperia_Mobile() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Clicking on Xperia");
        xperia = mobile.clickOnXperia();
    }

    @When("^Read Sony Xperia Cost on Details Page$")
    public void read_Sony_Xperia_Cost_on_Details_Page() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Fetching cost of product on Details Page");
        detailCost = xperia.getXperiaPrice();
    }

    @Then("^Verify That both the prices are same$")
    public void verify_That_both_the_prices_are_same() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        log.info("Verifying that the cost of products on both pages is same");
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(detailCost, listCost);
            log.info("############# Test Case 2 Passed ###########");
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Price of Xperia in List and Details Page is not same");
            log.info("############# Test Case 2 Failed ###########");
        }
    }
}
```

**Base Page Class**

```
package Util;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BasePage {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static Properties prop;

    public static void initialization() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", util.FFDRIVER_PATH);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(util.PAGELOAD_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(util.IMPICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(util.URL);
    }

    public static void closeSession() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your feature file?

Comment: in glue, try passing stepDefinition.SortByNameSteps (i.e. full class path)

Comment: @ShivamMishra I tried doing as you have suggested but it's not working. It's saying that I need to implement the missing steps . I guess its not able to detect step definition class this way.

Comment: @UmangBhatia ok. Seems like cucumber is running ALL the Before and After methods it could find in the stepDefinition package. Can you try separating the packages for step def classes for each test cases? Passing only the relevant stepDef package in glue should resolve your issue.

Comment: @ShivamMishra I tried this and it did work but what will I do if I am dealing with 100+ test cases ? Surely making a package for each test case individually won't be feasible . Plus what will I do if I want to run all the feature files at once in a suite?

Comment: @UmangBhatia check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem was Cucumber is executing ALL the `@Before` and `@After` methods defined in the various classes of `stepDefinition` package. It is also the expected case since cucumber does not know which methods to execute unless you exclusively tell it to.

One simple solution to this would be to create different packages to hold different classes for each test case but as OP correctly pointed out that it would not be a feasible solution for like say 100 cases and this approach will limit the user to not be able to execute all the feature files from a single runner class.

**Solution -**

1) For this particular case, use [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [`@AfterClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html)Junit annotations instead of `@Before` and `@After` cucumber annotation. Since each test case Step Def has its own class, this should work for your case.

2) You can also use [Tagged Hooks](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/tagged-hooks-in-cucumber/). It is basically attaching a hook to a name inside a scenario. Ex -

Feature file -

```
@Test1
Scenario: blah blah

@Test2
Scenario: blah blah 2
```

Step Definition -

```
    @Before("@Test1")
    public void beforeFirst(){
        //This will run only before the Scenario Test1
    }   

    @Before("@Test2")
    public void beforeSecond(){
       //This will run only before the Scenario Test2
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess this would work. Another alternate solution that hit me just now is that we can also use  tagged hooks. I tried it just now and seems to serve the purpose well

Comment: @UmangBhatia Yes! Added it to my answer for the sake of completeness. Please accept my answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Done bro! Thanks again